# SQL Server Agent won't start

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-agent, configuration

When I'm trying to start SQL Server Agent, I got this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   Unable to start service SQLAGENT$SQL_NAGA on server NAGA. (mscorlib)
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   The SQLAGENT$SQL_NAGA service on NAGA started and then stopped. (ObjectExplorer)

Can you guys help me to solve this problem? I'm using 2014 Enterprise Edition.

Using `@@version` I got this:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64) 
Jun  9 2015 12:06:16 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: )
```

I also found this error event related to SQL Server Agent in the Windows Event Log

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SQLAgent$SQL_NAGA
Date:          1/31/2016 6:17:24 PM
Event ID:      103
Task Category: Service Control
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Naga
Description:
SQLServerAgent could not be started
(reason: Unable to connect to server 'NAGA\SQL_NAGA'; SQLServerAgent cannot start).
```

**UPDATE:**

Error log of SQL Server Agent

[image]

SQL Server and SQL Server Agent both logged on as Local System Account

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not Enterprise Evaluation Edition?

Comment: Also review your Agent Drive location and Agent startup settings as recommended in these articles
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140493/after-upgrade-to-2016-sql-server-agent-cant-connect-to-instance
and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/04/30/sql-server-agent-cannot-start-because-the-instance-of-the-server-instance-is-not-the-expected-instance/ Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error would be where I would start looking:

> SQLServer Error: 27, Registry information is corrupt or missing.
>   Make sure the provider installed and registered correctly. [SQLSTATE 08001]

If you are able to perform a repair of the installation, that should resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Set the SQL Agent service to `Automatic(Delayed)`. The first thing it will do is try to connect to SQL Server, and if SQL Server hasn't finished starting yet, SQL Agent can fail. Delaying the start for SQL Agent will give SQL Server the chance to finish.

Comment: I set the SQL Agent Service to Automatic(Delayed) and restarted the SQL server service. But still Agent Service won't start. Getting the error "Service started and then stopped"

Answer (score 2):

ODBC driver error can cause problems on systems with multiple versions or upgrade scenarios. Take a look at these articles. This can generate network related errors.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/3185365
and 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955763
The solution is to update to the latest ODBC driver.

Comment: +1 However in our case (updating OBDC drivers for SQL2019), the **latest version did not work**.  Instead we had to go for a single version increase which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the service is running. If not you can start the service using one of these alternatives:

- services.msc
- net start SQLSERVERAGENT
- Using SQL Server Configuration Manager
- Windows service manager start SQL Agent service (automatic)

If the service is running, you can try this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Start SQL Server Agent when ‘Agent XPs disabled’
---------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------
--http://zarez.net/?p=2720
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SQL Agent service user (the one in services.msc) is a valid login on the SQL Server instance.

If it is, look for 18456 errors in the SQL log to see why that login can't log in.

Specific details in the MSDN [Select an Account for the SQL Server Agent Service article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx)